# Skype message sharing

Tags: ios, skype

I want to implement Skype Instant Message sending/sharing on my iOS app. I just want to share certain link on skype.

Following is the code is am using:

```
//skype sharing

    BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
    NSString * msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi. Check it out.\n %@  %@",[[self Detail] objectForKey:@"title"],self.shareLink];
    NSString * urlSkype = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:?chat=%@",msg];
    NSURL * SkypeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlSkype stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if(installed)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:SkypeURL];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
    }
```

If skype is installed, then also the above code isn't working as wanted. I want that the message-`msg` should automatically be sent(as Instant Message) to the Skype contact I select from the iOS app.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, as written here in, Skype URI API Reference Documentation.

[image]

Or direct link, [Skype URI API reference for Chat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882(v=office.15).aspx#chats)

And here is, [Skype URI tutorial: iOS apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745885(v=office.15).aspx#How)

They also added a note there,

> With the recent redesign of the Skype for iOS client, URIs are not currently supported on the Skype for iOS 5.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the user is able to start a new chat with the selected Skype contact, but not able to send a message immediately.

To start a new chat with a given user:

```
NSString * urlSkype = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:skype.test.user.1?chat",msg];
```

Check the [Skype URI API reference (Chat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882(v=office.15).aspx#chats) for more info.

Comment: Is it regarding the whole chat URI or only for the 'topic' URL parameter?